# Split a text file into multiple text files nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am fairly new to NodeJS. I have a text large file of data like below and I need to split each chunk into multiple text files dynamically. How can I achieve this using Nodejs?

LargeFile.txt

```
Name: John
Age: 18
Address: Washington

Name: Doe
Age: 23

Name: Randy
Address: Tennessee
```

Expected outcomes should be like this

John.txt

```
Name: John
Age: 18
Address: Washington
```

Doe.txt

```
Name: Doe
Age: 23
```

Randy.txt

```
Name: Randy
Address: Tennessee
```

Comment: Can you add your desired outcome please ?

Comment: @BarLevin added the desired outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your problem to separate content by line spaces? If so, you can use the `split()` method and split your text by `\n\n` or `\r\n\r\n` (the characters for two newlines).

```js
// required module
const fs = require('fs');

// read the file content
const str = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/alldata.txt');

// detect newline character
let newline = '\n';
let twonewlines = '\n\n';

if (str.indexOf('\r\n\r\n') > -1) {
  newline = '\r\n';
  twonewlines = '\r\n\r\n';
}

// split
let arr = str.split(twonewlines);

// save items as new files
arr.forEach((data, idx)=> {
  /* format of data will be:
   * Name: XX
   * Age: YY
   * Address: ZZ
   */

  // get name
  let firstRow = data.slice(0, data.indexOf(newline)); // get "Name: XX"
  let name = firstRow.split(': ')[1]; // get "XX"

  // write to file
  fs.writeFileSync(`/path/to/${name}.txt`, data);
});
```

You can utilize the Promise or Callback version of the File System (`fs`) module for better performance.

Comment: No. My expected solution is to separate chunk of data for each name and write them into separate text file. Have added the desired outcome in my post.

Comment: Ok, I've added steps for retrieving the name from each data and use it as the file name.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain how the if statement works

Comment: There're two common styles in displaying a newline character. First is POSIX-style (in Unix) that uses `\n`, second is Windows-style that uses `\r\n`. A file written on Linux/Mac computer will have `\n` for a newline by default. If the file is written on Windows computer, it will have `\r\n` for a newline.

In the program, I assume the file is written on a Linux/Mac computer, so the default is `\n` for newline and `\n\n` for double newlines. But, we need to check whether `\r\n\r\n` exists. If it exists, all newlines must use Windows-style which is `\r\n`, and `\r\n\r\n` for double newlines.

Comment: May I know why is it defined with index position [1] instead of [0] for "//get XX" line of code?

Comment: It's because `"Name: XX"` is split by `": "` into an array `["Name", "XX"]`. So, `"XX"` is on index-1. Index-0 is `"Name" `.